# Migration from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2016. Will workflow works after migration?

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, migration, sql-server, 2016

I have just migrated a web application from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2016 with SQL server 2016, however, i have read some blog that says workflow manager does not support SQL server 2016, so will migrated workflow works or I need to downgrade to SQL server 2014?

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Does-SharePoint-Workflow-Manager-support-SQL-2016/td-p/21389

Answer (score 1):

Found [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/workflowteam/2017/07/25/workflow-manager-1-0-now-supported-on-windows-server-2016-with-cu4/) and now my 2013 workflows are back!

> We have completed our validation work and are pleased to announce that
>   Workflow Manager Server 1.0 now supports the following platforms when
>   used in a SharePoint Server 2016 environment:
>
> .NET 4.6+ (when using Service Bus Server 1.1 with KB3086798) Windows
>   Server 2016 Windows 10 x64 (for development purposes) SQL Server 2014
>   & SQL Server 2016 To install the supported Workflow Manager Farm on a
>   Windows Server 2016 machine:
>
> Install WFM 1.0 Refresh from WebPI. This would install SB 1.1 and
>   includes KB3086798. Install WFM 1.0 Cumulative Update 3 from WebPI.
>   Install WFM 1.0 Cumulative Update 4 from WebPI.